# Force Ubuntu to identify LAMP php installation

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, lampp

I have installed LAMP in my ubuntu environment (16.04) which has apache, php (7.0.9), mysql...

Although the php functionality is there, when i type 'php -v' in the terminal, i get the message

> The program 'php' can be found in the following packages 
>   * php7.0-cli  
>   * hhvm

which as i understand means that ubuntu does not recognise the php installation from LAMP .

---

Is there a way to tell ubuntu that there is a php installation in opt/lamp... in order to recognise it?

Comment: Why do you think you have installed it? could you try the command:  apache2 -v ?

Comment: What did you exactly do for installing the LAMP?

Comment: i have downloaded XAMPP from apachefriends website (https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html), run the file and followed the wizard... i though this was installing stuff to my system

Comment: Read this. May be this will help you. https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04-lamp/

Comment: For the record, "The program 'xxx' can be found in the following packages" is just Ubuntu's ostensibly helpful way of saying "command not found".